# How could a sterile intelligent race form its own nation(tribe)?

Tags: humans, aliens

Say 200 years from now we have had encounter of the sixth kinds. (the one that involves voluntary interspecies breeding) let say human can breed with these intelligent alien to produce a sterile hydrid with a life span of fifty years max even with advanced genetic therapy, how could these hybrids create their own nation including a sizable military force?

Comment: Reminder to close voters: Please don't vote to close questions without leaving commentary. The problem cannot be fixed if the OP is not made aware of it.

Comment: First off, this is generally a terrible question, since it doesn't define 'encounter of the sixth kind,' explain the reason that tribe is in parenthesis in the title, or explain how these humans and aliens are able to make sterile offspring. Regardless of that, the question is too broad because the question indicates no criteria by which a correct answer can be judged.

Comment: @kingledion: thank you for the criticism, you're right that I didn't explain the mechanism behind interspecies breeding nor set the criteria. That's because doing so will cause more confusions, been there done that so I choose the lesser of two evils.

Comment: Further to @XandarTheZenon's comment. The close votes are due to the question being too broad as it will be hard (impossible) to provide an answer covering every aspect of nation-building without writing multiple essays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the entire answer,  I will assume that these Hybrids are, at least, as intelligent as the smarter of their creators, and are in above-average physical condition.

#### Founding a country

200 years from now, with Aliens in the mix, it is reasonable to think that there is an unoccupied planet for them to claim. If both Humans and Aliens are using and breeding them to be slaves, it is highly possible that they bind in opposition to their creators and decide to take their independance.

Another possibility for their uprising could be a telepathic link, which was not foreseen by the creators. Hybrids can communicate vague ideas together - one being independance. United by the thought, they decide to take their independance.

#### Defending a country

This point is void if both Humans and Aliens are fine with Hybrids taking independance - for instance because they think their sterility will subdue them faster than war.

If either Humans or Aliens oppose their independance, they will need armament to protect their new nation. Some of the Hybrids have probably been associated with high-end military programs and have extensive technological knowledge. They managed to plot their uprising and smuggled a lot of weapons, and acquired the knowledge to build more advanced weapons once they settle - but most of all, they sabotaged the most dangerous weapons of their creators, avoiding instant obliteration.

#### Perpetuating a country

These Hybrids are sterile, but have advanced technology at their disposal.

- Are they uncurably sterile ? Genetic engineering might allow them to procreate.
- They can probably clone themselves using a process similar to the one that birthed them

Now assume that they are sterile, and have no way to duplicate themselves. The only way to obtain a Hybrid is to have a human and an alien reproducing. Desperate to increase their numbers and secure their future, the Hybrids only see one solution. They need *breeders*.

The Hybrids decide to raid human and alien settlements, and abduct young people. They force them to reproduce until they die. They genetically engineer the females to extend their fertility by a decade, and use heavy medical assistance to ensure they produce at least one child per year. Those who can't reproduce can't be set free because they would talk, so they die.

Answer (score 0):

### Extreme Abilities

If the hybrids had accelerated intellectual and physical capabilities compared to normal humans and aliens, they could outperform both during their 50 year lifespan. If their abilities were doubled, then in 50 years, they would be able to achieve what one of their parents could in 100 years.

### Reproduction

If they have access to the same [cloning technology we currently have](https://www.genome.gov/25020028/cloning-fact-sheet/), they could easily breed more of their own kind, even though they are sterile. If done in large enough quantities, they could produce enough individuals to populate a nation as well as a large army.

Comment: Current cloning technology isn't quite up to cloning humans. A problem with spindle proteins, but in 200 years time those problems should be solved. The interesting question may be whether sterile hybrid females can bear cloned children.Also, most women don't want to be used as baby factories. Very sensible too. This may need the non-trivial technology of gestation chambers to make up the numbers.

Comment: @a4android your latter point is a question of culture. A civilization that needed breeders would value them above all others. Just like we put artists and sports pros on a pedestal, they would idolize breeders. Such a civilization wouldn't have too hard a time finding volunteers...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky It is a question of culture. This is a minority culture. Who knows what their status is in the greater society around them. Artists and sports pros go through Hell to reach their pedestals. Will women want to be idolized breeders? Demographics show given the chance women don't want to be breeders. That's why I suggested reproductive technology. But social matters are always complex.

Comment: @a4android true, not ALL women want to be breeders, but there are those who, for instance, enjoy being pregnant and so engage in surrogacy. And there are more who might be willing if the price was right. If this minority put enough cultural importance on the matter, then they would pool resources to pamper these volunteers.